# Custom UI in react jsonschema form for ArrayFieldTemplate

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using `react jsonschema form` in my application and handling an array in the response / request. What I have done is to use my custom UI instead of using `{element.children}` which through some magic creates the html and has all props available. Below is my code

```
    ArrayFieldTemplate = (props) => {
    console.log('ArrayfieldTemplate', props);
    let span = 2;
    props.items.map(element => (
        console.log('ArrayfieldTemplate element children', element.children.props.formData.Notes)            
        ));

    return (

        <div className={props.className} style={{ "display": "block" }}>               
            <Table responsive striped>                   
                <tbody>
            {                   
                props.items &&
                        props.items.map(element => (
                       
                        <tr key={element.index}>
                                <td>
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        id={element.children.props.idSchema.UserNotes.$id}
                                        value={element.children.props.formData.UserNotes}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />
                                    {/*{element.children}*/}
                                </td>
                            <td className="align-text-bottom" style={{ verticalAlign:"bottom", textAlign:"left" }}>
                                <Button bsStyle="danger" className={"btn-xs"}
                                    onClick={(event) => { this.dropElement(event, element, element.index); }}
                                    >Delete</Button>
                                   
                               
                            </td>                                
                        </tr>
                                    
                                              
                ))
            }
                </tbody>
            </Table>

            {props.canAdd && (
                <div>
                    <p className=" array-item-add">
                        <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={props.onAddClick}>
                            Add
                        </Button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I want to show the `input type="text"` and `button` inside a table. There are few other fields also in the array `{element.children.props.formData}` which I have removed for brevity.
Now when the first-time page loads there is no `UserNotes` in the database so I see the blank text box but when I enter something and click on `submit` this array is still empty when the request is received at the backend.

I am using `react with typescript`.

Below is the form code

```
    return (
            <div>
                <Form id={"form"} schema={this.state.schema}
                    formData={this.state.data}
                    uiSchema={uiSchema}
                    onChange={() => { }}
                    onError={this.onError}
                    ArrayFieldTemplate={this.ArrayFieldTemplate} 
                    FieldTemplate={this.CustomFieldTemplate}
                    onSubmit={this.setSettingData}
                    validate={this.validate}
                    liveValidate={false}
                    showErrorList={false}
                    widgets={this.widgets}
                    fields={this.fields}
                    noHtml5Validate={true}
                />
            </div>
        );
```

I could not find any example where custom ui is used with ArrayFieldTemplate in react jsonschema form. Can anyone please help me? Can't replace react jsonschema form because this code is already in use in production. I am just trying to add the ArrayFieldTemplate with custom UI.